# script conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 scripts on my page and I’d like to add them altogther but am not too sure how.
The first is

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
sfHover = function() {
var sfEls = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("LI");
for (var i=0; i<sfEls.length; i++) {
    sfEls[i].onmouseover=function() {
        this.className+=" sfhover";
    }
    sfEls[i].onmouseout=function() {
        this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" sfhover\\b"), "");
    }
}
}
if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", sfHover);
//--><!]]>
</script>
```

With the below since I've added the stock control message change, the reload doesn’t work. I’ve added a no conflict script but I don't think I've added it correctly. I'd like to put all 5 scripts together (above and below) in one tag that works - can anyone help out?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 // 
  function ImageLoadFailed() {
      window.event.srcElement.style.display = "None";
 }
 // reload after adding product  
 function AddProductExtras(){
     document.location.reload(true);
 }
 // for stock control - change message  
 function AddProductExtras(catalogId,productId,ret) {
     var td = document.getElementById('catProdTd_'+productId);
     if (td.innerHTML == 'This product is unavailable or out of stock.')
     td.innerHTML = 'Product added successfully.';
}
jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery's `noConflict()` merely prevents it from declaring the `$` shortcut to jQuery - it is not a magic bullet for ensuring any two given scripts do not conflict. Actually, I can't see that you're using any jQuery. Also, your code seems geared towards IE only, no other browsers (since you use only `attachEvent` and reference the event object on `window`, for example).

Answer (score 2):

create one js file and in that paste all your 5 script codes.
And include this javascript file on your index page as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="name.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to call it in a new js page and link it to your main page.

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
```